# Athena/Presto find key with the max value in JSON object

Tags: json, amazon-athena, presto

I have a column in Athena (type string) with json like this:

```
{
    "key1": 1.1,
    "key2":2.2,
    "key3": 3.3
}
```

How do I write a query which will return me the JSON key with the highest value (in this example it is `key3`) for each row and the associated value (`3.3`).

Note: I don't know what are the key names in advance (and there can be several)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your json as `MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER)` and process it. For example (this uses [`map_entries`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_entries) function to turn map into array of rows, [`reduce`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce) array function and relies on default row naming convention) :

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (JSON '{
            "key1": 1.1,
            "key2":2.2,
            "key3": 3.3
        }'),
        (JSON '{
            "key0": 1.1,
            "key1":4.4,
            "key2": 3.3
        }')) AS t (json))

SELECT row.field0 as key, row.field1 as value
FROM
    (SELECT reduce(
      map_entries(CAST(json as MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER))),
      ROW (null, null),
      (agg, curr) -> IF (agg.field1 > curr.field1, agg, curr),
      s -> s) as row
    FROM dataset)
```

Output:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| key3 | 3 |
| key1 | 4 |

Comment: @dg428 was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a way but it seems very convoluted, would appreciate if anyone else has a better solution. Assuming there is a column called Id, and the json is stored in a separate column:

```
with d as (
    select id,
    CAST(json_extract(json_col, '$') AS MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)) as s
    from TABLE_NAME
),

d2 as (
    select *,
    element_at(s, key) AS value
    from d
    cross join unnest(map_keys(s)) AS sx(key)
),

d3 as (
    select id, key, value,
    rank() over (partition by id order by value desc) as order
    from d2
    order by id, order
)


select id, key, value from d3 where order = 1
```

Basically first cast the JSON object into a map, then unnest the map keys and cross join and in a separate column store the value, then compute the rank partitioned by the value, then only choose those rows with rank = 1